# How to add custom Icon to buttons on buttonpads in mapinfo?

Tags: cartography, mapinfo, mapbasic

I have made buttons with icons availabe in mapinfo but now i want to add custom icon. Is it possible my code is as follows:

```
  Include "icons.def"
  Declare Sub Main
  Declare Sub button_prompt
  Sub Main
 Create ButtonPad "Custom" As 
PushButton
Icon MI_ICON_ZOOM_QUESTION
Calling button_prompt
HelpMsg "Item1"
fixed

Alter ButtonPad "Custom"
Add Separator
Add PushButton
Icon MI_ICON_GRABBER
Calling button_prompt
HelpMsg "Item2"
fixed
 End Sub
 Sub button_prompt
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help with creating custom buttons.

http://twiav.nl/files/TWIAV_TIP_MB001.pdf

Also try the MapInfo-L mailing list:

http://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l